# String date to SQL datetime conversion 'Mon Dec 09 2019 12:00:54'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field in database which has date time saved in string format like this.
**Mon Dec 09 2019 12:00:54**

I want to convert this to SQL Datetime.

I tried by splitting but it is not working for me.

Comment: Fix the schema and use an appropriate type -- some date/time type in this case, **not** a string.

Comment: If you did make attempts, you need to share them; we can't tell you why they're not working if you don't show us what it was you tried. But @stickybit it right, fix your design. `varchar` is *not* a one size fits all data type, just like `'Mon Dec 09 2019 12:00:54'` isn't **after** `'Fri Jul 30 2021 12:19:19'`, but it *is* according to *your* data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server is pretty flexible about recognizing formats for date/time values, but not with the day of the week.  So, let's get rid of that:

```
select convert(datetime, stuff(dt_col, 1, 4, ''))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0d3dae33aee643207f1607d3574d72b) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this task is part of a move to a more appropriate data type?

You can use

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('Mon Dec 09 2019 12:00:54' AS datetime USING 'en-US')
```